# Using mod_rewrite to strip certain GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, variables, get

I'm a mod_rewrite noob and I'm getting a headache trying to figure out something that should be simple.  What I'm trying to do is strip out unwanted variables from a URL displayed after a GET form is used.  In other words, I'm trying to change this:

```
stats.php?gender=W&team_id=88&btnGet=Get+Stats
```

to this:

```
stats.php?team_id=88
```

Please help me!

EDIT: All I had to do was remove the "name" attributes in my form on 'gender' and the submit button.  Thanks to too much php and Gumbo for the solution!  Of course, there was a much easier way of accomplishing this.  :)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Is it for SEO reasons? If so you can use the canonical meta tag so that google will ignore extra query string data. see: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: It's part of a self-referencing GET form that also uses Ajax.  A person selects a gender and then a team and presses "Get Stats".  I want the extra variables removed from the URL just to tidy things up.  Basically, the form is only used to figure out the team_id and the stats are displayed below the form.

Comment: Just don’t give the submit button a name.

Comment: That’s also what *too much php* suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would this even achieve? The URL will still appear exactly the same in the user's address bar, and PHP is more capable of ignoring abitrary `$_GET` variables than mod_rewrite will ever be.

Try removing '`name="btnGet"`' attribute from your submit button and drop the '`gender`' field as well. You can also use Javascript to dynamically remove form elements which aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} team_id=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} btnGet
RewriteRule stats.php stats.php?team_id=%1 [R]
```

You can't match query strings with RewriteRule -- you have to use RewriteCond.

As "too much" says, just doing the rewriting won't cause any visible change to the user unless you reload the page. So you need the [R] to force a redirect instead of a simple rewrite, which may not work for the logic of your program.